# Assigning an argument of a class(a) to another class's(b) variable by calling class(b) constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, private, protected

What I need to do:  **//Constructor that initializes b to inVal1 and the inherited a
   //  to inVal2 by using the BaseExample constructor.
   public DerivedExample(int inVal1, int inVal2);**

How do you call the class BaseExample's variable, in class DerivedExample by using BaseExample constructor in DerivedExample constructor? I have checked numerous articles in stackoverflow and it hasn't helped figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is my code:

BaseExample Class (and no I am not allowed to make the variable protected on this example):

```
public class BaseExample {
    private int a;

    public BaseExample(int inVal) {
        a = inVal;
    }

    public BaseExample(BaseExample other){
        a = other.a;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(a);
    }


}
```

DerivedExample Class (**Updated**):

```
public class DerivedExample extends BaseExample {
    private int b;



public DerivedExample(int inVal1, int inVal2){
        super(inVal2);
        a = inVal2;

    }
}
```

The super method worked. Now how would I call it if I am asked this:

**Returns a reference to a string containing the value stored in
    the inherited varible a followed by a colon followed by the
    value stored in b
   public String toString()**

I have tried this:

```
public String toString(){
            int base = new BaseExample(b);

            return String.valueOf(base:this.b);

        }
```

If I put two returns, it would give me an error of unreachable code. And if I put a super inside the valueOf it doesn't work. And this doesn't work as well. How is this executed?

Comment: Google for "constructor tutorial inheritance java", click on first link, get the answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java) might be of use to you. Super can be used to call the base class's constructor to instantiate its variables for you.