# Reason for using super

Tags: java, super

While studying another person's code, I've come across this:

```
    public class TestFailedError extends AssertionError {  

        private final String testName;  
        private final String testData; 

        public TestFailedError(final String testName, final String message) {  
            super(getDetailMessage(testName, message));
            this.testName = testName;
            this.testData = testName;
        } 
  private static String getDetailMessage(String testData, String message) {
        return "Test case " +testData+ " failed :"+ message;
        }
    }
```

I don't understand the point of super() here. [Reading up on super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java) didn't help.
Reason the linked question didn't help is because it provides examples of 
`super.variable` and `super.method`, while mine was `super(method)`, so wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: The answer you referred is very clear and simple? What is it exactly you don't understand?

Comment: `super` is referring to the super-class in this case `AssertionError`. In this particular case it is calling the constructor of `AssertionError`.

Comment: **What** do you not understand?

Comment: Dear downvoter, I've explicitly linked to a different question trying to show I did some research.

Comment: Calling the [`Exception(String message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.String)) constructor is a common idiom when you're writing custom exceptions. This way the detail message of the exception shows nicely in logs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super(getDetailMessage(testName, message));` is calling to `AssertionError` constructor, which `TestFailedError` is inherits from, and will save the `String` it received. It will look like

```
public AssertionError(String str) {
    // save str to local member
}
```

The `str` variable will contain the return string from the method `getDetailMessage`.

Comment: So is the code equivalent to AssertionError(getDetailMessage(testName,message))?

Comment: @AndreyDoronin only this specific line, yes.