# What is the keyword super doing in this java method?

Tags: java

So there's no class extension [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java), so I'm trying to understand what the *super()* method call is doing?

I could understand super if the keyword *extend* was being used as in the referenced SO question, but it is not.

```
 public class Solver {
   private Node result;

   private class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
     Node prev;
     Board value;
     int moves = 0;
     int priority;
     public Node(Board value, Node previous) {
       super();
       //stuff
       //stuff
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
       //stuff
     }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Node node) {
        //stuff
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: It is calling super class'es constructor. Every class in Java stems from Object class. `private class Node` extends Object.

Comment: Here not needed actually, either you do it explicitly or compiler will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a super class called `Object`, so it will invoke constructor of `Object`.

Comment: But why call super in Node then?  Why not just call it in Solver?  I don't understand why you would call the Object constructor in the first place

Comment: U can go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: @Nona `Solver` and `Node` are two different classes.  The constructor for `Solver` is called when you create a `Solver` object, and the constructor for `Node` is called when you create a `Node` object.  If `Node` were a subclass of something interesting, then calling `super()` in `Solver` wouldn't help at all when you create a `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not extends any class then by default the inherited class is Object so it calls Object class constructor.