# Java: accessing Child class methods from parent

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it possible to access the child class method from parent class?

```
public class C1 {
    public C1(){
         System.out.println("Constructor C1");
    }
}

public class C2 extends C1{
    public void m1(){
         System.out.println("print from m1");
    }
}

public class C3 extends C1{
    public void m2(){
         System.out.println("print from m2");
    }
}

public class TestMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         C1 c1 = new C1();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to access c1.m1() & c1.m2() without initializing for child class?

Comment: using `super`? ie. in `c2.m1()` you call `super.m1()` it'll automatically calls `m1()` in c2's parent. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java)

Comment: No you cannot. Think of this case if both C2 and C3 define a method `m3()` then which method should java invoke when you call `c1.m3()`? `C2.m3()` or `C3.m3`?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't: `c1` is a reference referring to an object of type `C1`. There's no conversion that you can use to fool Java into thinking that it's a `C2` or a `C3`.

What you would *normally* do is to define an `abstract` function `mSomething` in `C1`, *implement* that function in the child classes and use something like

`C1 c = new C2();`

`c.mSomething()` would then call, *polymorphically*, the required function in the child class.

Another alternative would be to make `m1` and `m2` `static`, and have them take a `C1` instance as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Bathsheba. I was looking for some alternative. The purpose is logically segregating the methods in three different classes and invoking all from the same point. Doesn't look feasible. :(

Comment: I've added an alternative approach at the end.