# Accessing child class methods from the parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I'm not sure which title to give to this question so if You have any idea I'll modify it right away. Anyway my question is simple:
I have a class "User" and a class "Student" that extends User; when I create the object using `User u = new Student()`, is there a way to access the methods from the "Student" class even if I decalred it as a "User"? I have a "login()" method inside my student class but when I try to call it with `u.login()` it tells me that there is no method login for the object User. Does that mean that to use my Student class methods I have to declare it as `Student s = new Student()`? I hope my question is clear. Thank you all.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387207/can-a-parent-call-child-class-methods)

Comment: `User u = new Student()`
With object `u` You can call only `User` class methods and it's overridden implementations in `Student` class if any
You can't call the methods that is not belong `User`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: accessing Child class methods from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929052/java-accessing-child-class-methods-from-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have a *Student* object type, your reference is of type *User*. You will only have access to methods/fields (that are not private) of your *User* reference.

Think of this remote - tv analogy: you have a tv with multiple functions, like browsing tv channels, youtube, netflix. However, your remote can only browse tv channels, so you will not have access to youtube and netflix. Getting a new remote would work.

What works:

- `Student s = new Student()`;
- moving the `login()` method inside *User*. You may also want to override this method inside your *Student* class to include *Student* capabilities. Then you can call `u.login()` and the overridden version of the method would be invoked even though the object reference has *User* type ([further info](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_polymorphism.asp));
- casting the reference type from *User* to *Student*: `((Student) u).login()` ([further info](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting)).

Answer (score 0):

A parent class does not have knowledge of child classes.
Here, `User u = new Student()` u is of reference type `User` which can't invoke child method `login()`.

```
class User {
    
    public String name;

    public User(String name)
    {   System.out.println("Constructing User object");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Student extends User {

    public String studentName;

    public Student( String studentName)
    {
        super(studentName);
        System.out.println("Constructing Student object");
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public void login()
    {
        System.out.println("login method"); 
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        User u = new Student("testname");
        u.login(); //compilation error []
        Student s = new Student("testname1");
        s.getName(); //child can call parent class method.
    }
}
```