# What does the default constructor in the class OBJECT do?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, superclass

I'm a Java beginner learning about Java compiler rules as below:

1. If the class has no super class, extend it to Object class
2. If the class has no constructor, add a default no-parameter constructor
3. If the first line of the constructor is not "super()" or "this()", add "super()" to call the default constructor of the super class.

I understand that all objects we create are derived from the super class Object.
My question is what does the constructor in the Object class do when called?

Edit: My question is about what the constructor does in the class Object? I'm aware that subclasses call superclass's constructor by default.

For example, I have the following code (where I explicitly extend to Object and call super() to illustrate what the compiler does). My question is, what does the call to super() do?

```
public class Person extends Object
{
    private String name;
    public Person(String n)
        {   
            super();
            this.name = n;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is literally no reason to ever write `extends Object` in Java.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov agree. The above code is shown by the instructor to illustrate how the compiler works.

Comment: Also, this: `If the class has no constructor, add a default no-parameter constructor` is a wrong rule of thumb as well.

Comment: You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java). Hope this will help you.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov could you elaborate on why the rule is wrong please?

Comment: @misaikucing, I will actually back off from that last statement, I was not realizing that you were talking about compiler. But then, if we talk about compiler, then the first thing it actually does in constructor is it loads a `this` variable (you can open any compiled class file and see for yourself)

Comment: @misaikucing Because it doesn't apply to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Not in the case of `java.lang.Object`. All the default constructor contains is a `return` opcode.

Comment: @EJP, I'm pretty sure it almost does, except Object actually does have a constructor (defined by JVM as a special case), so compiler will not need to add it.

Comment: @EJP but I see that the Object class does have an empty constructor though https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Exactly as I said. The constructor for `java.lang.Object` is not 'defined by the JVM as a special case.` Time for you to stop guessing.

Comment: @EJP, I would disagree that rule is not applied to `Object` - the rule action is *not applicable* to Object, however, because rule predicate does not hold.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't know what 'rule' or 'predicate' you are talking about, or what the sophistical difference between 'applied' and 'applicable' might be, or who used any of these terms in the first place. It certainly wasn't me. You seem to be confused about what I'm referring to. It is your claim that 'the first thing it actually does in constructor is it loads a `this` variable'. This is untrue, and that is verifiable, and explicable by reference to the JLS #8.8.9. Not 'defined by the JVM'.

Comment: @EJP, I'm looking at compiled bytecode right now, and I see there: `0 aload_0 [this] 1 invokespecial java.lang.Object() 4 return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what does the call to super() do?

It calls the default constructor for `java.lang.Object`. And to answer what you seem to be really asking, from the [Java Language Specification, #8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> 8.8.9. Default Constructor
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared. The form of the default constructor for a top level class, member class, or local class is as follows:
>
> The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).
>
> The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a non-private inner member class, where the default constructor implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class (§8.8.1, §15.9.2, §15.9.3).
>
> The default constructor has no throws clauses.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class `Object`, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

Note the final paragraph.

Comment: So it means the constructor in the class Object does nothing?

Comment: @misaikucing There is no 'it means' about it. It *explicitly says* that the default constructor of `java.lang.Object` has an empty body, and you can see that for yourself via `javap -c java.lang.Object`.

Comment: very well explained, got it!

Answer (score 1):

All Java classes that don't have any explicit superclass, extend from `Object`, except for `Object` itself. There's no need to make it explicit in your code, the compiler will take care of.

Also, the `super()` call in the constructor will invoke the constructor of `Object`. If you look at the implementation, you'll see that Object doesn't have any constructor at all, so it'll use an implicit empty constructor which does nothing. Details such as constructing a vtable to make sure that the inherited methods are there to use or initialising the object's monitor are not part of the constructor but are performed by the JVM implementation when the `new` operator is called.

```
public Object() {

}
```

The Object class has few methods that come handy in most of the classes. For example, the infamous `toString()` is implemented in the Object class. Also, the `hashCode()` is implemented there.

I'd recommend you to have a deep look at the Object.class file to understand what methods are inherited in every single Java class.

Regarding your 3 rules at the top, are "good" for academic purposes but never used in reality. You'll never see an explicit `extends Object`, and only call the `super()` or `this()` when you need to overwrite the default behaviour.

Also, avoid abusing of inheritance and use more composition (implement an interface), although, it depends on the every use case.

Comment: 'All Java classes that don't have any explicit superclass extend from `Object`', *except for `Object` itself.*

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I have the following code (where I explicitly extend to
>   Object and call super()). My question is, what does the call do
>   super() do?

Actually, `Object()` does nothing.
Now you should not reduce the constraint to invoke `super()` (with args or not) for any subclass constructor to the case where you have a class that doesn't extend a class explicitly.

This case is the only one where invoking `super()` may seem not really useful.
But as soon a class extends a class distinct from `Object`, this constraint makes really sense as the child construction has to apply first its parent construction.

But the language specifies this point in a general way. It has no exception  for classes that extend directly `Object`.
Probably because, it makes things more simple and that is not a real constraint as the compiler adds for you the call to the super default constructor : `super()`.