# Super method call with class name

Tags: android, super

Actually i was going through some android source code and found these

```
public static class ToggleService extends IntentService {
super(ToggleService.class.getname());
```

I am not able to understand the use of super and also its parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [super() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java)

Comment: i know the use of super.

Comment: Then you should know what it does: `super` calls the constructor of its parent class (that is `IntentService`) with the name of this class (`ToggleService`) as parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you have at look at the documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#IntentService(java.lang.String)

you will find that IntentService (base class of ToggleService) has a constructor which takes a string for debugging purposes. 
Super calls the constructor of the base class.
So ToggleService just supplies its own name for debug logs to be prefixed with it.

Answer (score 1):

Because ToggleService extends IntentService, by calling super from ToggleService, it is effectively calling IntentService's constructor, which is

```
     /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public IntentService(String name) {
        super();
        mName = name;
    }
```

ToggleService.class.getname() will return the name of the ToggleService class, which in this case is a concatenated string constructing the package name of ToggleService and "ToggleService".

For more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a keyword in `Java`. It refers to the immediate parents property.

```
super()            //refers parent's constructor
super.getMusic();  //refers to the parent's method
```

[Read More on super](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)