# Type Casting the 'super' Keyword in Java

Tags: java, this, super

In Java, it is possible to type cast the 'this' keyword to refer to any of a given class's superclasses. However, trying to do the same with the 'super' keyword results in a syntax error. Why does it not work with the 'super' keyword?

Comment: There is no such thing: instead you should cast to the superclass. I mean, you cast a value, not the keywork "this". Can you share a code snippet where you try this?

Comment: `super` is not the same as `this`: `Object o = this;` should work; `Object o = super;` not! `this` is an expression [15.8.3. this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3), `super` not

Comment: Because `super` doesn't refer to an object. Rather it is already an implicit typecast of `this` that can only be used in certain contexts, and as a free variable isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`this` has reference of object from which method or constructor is called.

`super` is used to refer parent class variables and methods. In short `super` keyword cannot be used for up casting.

You can create a method `returnThis(){return this;}` in parent class and call it in child class to get reference of parent class `this` for that particular object.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is used to refer to the super class and doesn't represent any object. `this` keyword represents the current object from within the this has been called.

super is used in three places:

1. To refer to super class property when there is a property conflict
2. to refer super class method in case of overriden methods.
3. To call parent class constructor.

Please read more about super [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java)