# What is the difference between "returning super.getItemId(position)" and just returning "return position"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

what is the difference between `returning super.getItemId(position)` and just returning `return position`?

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: ask me any quire if needed, thanks.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I just wanna know what difference it makes in recyclerView,

Comment: if you have answer please write one line about it thanks.@Pavneet_Singh

Comment: the concepts here is just `super` usage, `super.getItemId(position)` call a getItemId method of super class and use its return value

Comment: I understand that much, what I wanna know is the difference in term of result when returning from getItemId from recyclerView, thanks. @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: or the result is same ? @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: depends on the logic inside `getItemId` method, it could be any class or logic so do command or control+B on method and find it yourself :)

Comment: that's what I wanted to ask and discuss in my question, thanks anyway.@Pavneet_Singh

Comment: got it, please read the answer then though I wanted to explain the concept so that you can read it by yourself

Comment: ok , thanks please give an upvote if you can :) @Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the explanation about [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java/43538444).

Calling `super.getItemId(position)` will call the [getItemId](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/RecyclerView.java#L6387) method in the `Recyclerview` adapter class which will [return `-1`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/RecyclerView.java#L192) as

```
   /**
     * Return the stable ID for the item at <code>position</code>. If {@link #hasStableIds()}
     * would return false this method should return {@link #NO_ID}. The default implementation
     * of this method returns {@link #NO_ID}.
     *
     * @param position Adapter position to query
     * @return the stable ID of the item at position
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return NO_ID;
    }
```

so you must `override` `getItemId` method to send unique `int` ID(like `return position`) which will be used to find holders, children etc for animation, holder reusability and often during testing etc.