# Why super() is used in Constructor?

Tags: java, android, constructor, super, aide

I was learning about custom ArrayAdapter.Found this project on Github. I can't figure out why super is used here.

```
public AndroidFlavorAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<AndroidFlavor>Flavors) {

        super(context, 0, Flavors);
  }
```

When I remove super this error pops up.

X There is no applicable constructor to '()’

Any help?

Comment: On the other side, @fetive, I would recommend do your research first before posting here, that way you would learn better and everyone will benefit.

Comment: i tried to find out but didn't understand there explanation.:(

Comment: @omt66 can you please tell me why the second parameter in super is 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Every constructor needs to another constructor as the first thing it does<sup>1</sup>.  There are three ways to do this:

- A constructor can make an explicit `super` call, either with or without parameters.  The parameters types need to match the signature of a constructor declared in the superclass.
- A constructor can make an explicit `this` call.  This calls another constructor declared by this class.
- If there no explicit `super` or `this` class, an implicit `super()` call is added to the constructor by the Java compiler.  For this to work, there needs to be a constructor in the superclass with no arguments; i.e. a no-args constructor.

<sup>1 - Except for `java.lang.Object` which has no superclass.  Note that the bytecode verifier checks this.  If you use (say) a bytecode assembler to create a class with a constructor that doesn't call a superclass constructor, it will be rejected by the classloader.</sup>

---

So ...

> Why `super(...)` is used in Constructor?

To explicitly call a superclass constructor.  Notice that in this case you are passing arguments to the superclass constructor.

> When I remove super this error pops up: "There is no applicable constructor to '()’"

That is because the compiler cannot find the superclasses no-args constructor that is implicitly invoked if you don't have an explicit `super(...)` call.

> Can you please tell me why the second parameter in super is 0.

The javadocs for the superclass should explain what that means.  In this case, the 2nd parameter is a Resource ID.   I'm not sure that it makes sense, but I've seen it said that Resource ID 0 means `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the base class is probably doing the required initialization for the instance.